# Linux SPDIF input not working

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I bought this [product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0093L6SCG) , The problem is the SPDIF input not working

```
Linux 4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 10:09:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**$ lspci | grep -i audio**

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
03:01.0 Audio device: Creative Labs SB X-Fi
04:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

**AlsaMixer**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: pulseaudio does appear to see it alright.  You should also check alsa, in `alsamixer` you can use `<F6>` to select the card itself and then `<F5>` to select all controls (including inputs).  It may be muted in the alsa level.

Comment: @grochmal i already unmuted that but still no audio, image added to Q.

Comment: alsa is quite bad at naming the controls (mostly because hardware producers are even worse at it).  I know that it sounds stupid, but try to play around with the controls there (e.g. raise the Mic control).  You just never know how the actual controls affect the hardware.

Comment: @grochmal it tried a lot of things with alsa but nothing actually helped, i think alsa is not seeing it as SPDIF input port. because PluseAudio is not showing `Digital Stereo (Iec958) Input` option on this device. i have only `Digital Stereo (Iec958) Output`

Comment: hm... but alsa has an SPDIF capture device.  Before trying the kernel drivers I'd try `pavucontrol` (you may need to install it), `pavucontrol` is just like gnome's volume control but bypasses gnome.  `pavucontrol` sits directly in inside pulseaudio, it should see everythin pulseaudio receives from alsa (although you may need to tinker with the `Show:` menu).